# Text should wrap if checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview

I am working with android web-view and inside web-view i am displaying the webpage which is having `CSS`, `JavaScript` so I want that whenever I will select the check-box and try to zoom the page so it should wrap otherwise it should not. for that i tried to set the property of `CSS`-

**w.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" + "document.getElementByTagName('html')[0].style.whiteSpace='nowrap';})");**

but I am changing these properties by programming but it is not affecting the text content so please tell me how can I make the webpage text as wrapped if the check-box is selected and it should not wrap if the check-box is not selected, please provide me any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing a ')' after 'html', don't you?

Comment: getElementByTagName('html'[0] should be getElementByTagName('html')[0]

Comment: yes may be at the time of question posting by mistake i remove that